# What is the best approach to get all records related to a team in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarbean

Suppose that we have a team named 'Team A' having an id 'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee' and we want to get all the records where this team have been related for example all related Accounts, Leads, Contacts etc

There is also a possibility that a related record have a teamset where 'Team A' is a member of the teamset, can we somehow get even this related record ?

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

- Get all Teamsets for the team and store their IDs in an Array, eg. `$teamsetIDs`
- Loop over the global `$moduleList` *but*, skipping modules that do *not* use the team_security template
- For all non-skipped modules, construct SugarQuery, populating its `->where()` with `->in('team_set', $teamsetIDs)`. Then execute it to retrieve the desired record IDs.
  (If you don't want to also limit the results to the user's visibility, dont forget to specify `'team_security' => false` in the *SugarQuery* options)